# Swift: Switching handler from single tap to double tap causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

In the code below, capturing single taps works fine. Double taps, however, generate a EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception. This code lives inside of `GameScene.swift`.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    // Handle taps
    let tapHandler = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:Selector("doTap:"))
    tapHandler.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapHandler)
  }

func doTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

  // If tapHandler.numberOfTapsRequired = 2, this function never executes due to the exception.
  // If tapHandler.numberOfTapsRequired = 1, this function executes without problem.

}



Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (CODE=1, ADDRESS=0x10)

libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend:
    0x198617bc0 <+0>:   cmp    x0, #0
    0x198617bc4 <+4>:   b.le   0x198617c30               ; <+112>
    0x198617bc8 <+8>:   ldr    x13, [x0]
    0x198617bcc <+12>:  and    x9, x13, #0x1fffffff8
->  0x198617bd0 <+16>:  ldp    x10, x11, [x9, #16]
    0x198617bd4 <+20>:  and    w12, w1, w11
    0x198617bd8 <+24>:  add    x12, x10, x12, lsl #4
    0x198617bdc <+28>:  ldp    x16, x17, [x12]
    0x198617be0 <+32>:  cmp    x16, x1
    0x198617be4 <+36>:  b.ne   0x198617bec               ; <+44>
    0x198617be8 <+40>:  br     x17
    0x198617bec <+44>:  cbz    x16, 0x198617d80          ; _objc_msgSend_uncached_impcache
    0x198617bf0 <+48>:  cmp    x12, x10
    0x198617bf4 <+52>:  b.eq   0x198617c00               ; <+64>
    0x198617bf8 <+56>:  ldp    x16, x17, [x12, #-16]!
    0x198617bfc <+60>:  b      0x198617be0               ; <+32>
    0x198617c00 <+64>:  add    x12, x12, w11, uxtw #4
    0x198617c04 <+68>:  ldp    x16, x17, [x12]
    0x198617c08 <+72>:  cmp    x16, x1
    0x198617c0c <+76>:  b.ne   0x198617c14               ; <+84>
    0x198617c10 <+80>:  br     x17
    0x198617c14 <+84>:  cbz    x16, 0x198617d80          ; _objc_msgSend_uncached_impcache
    0x198617c18 <+88>:  cmp    x12, x10
    0x198617c1c <+92>:  b.eq   0x198617c28               ; <+104>
    0x198617c20 <+96>:  ldp    x16, x17, [x12, #-16]!
    0x198617c24 <+100>: b      0x198617c08               ; <+72>
    0x198617c28 <+104>: mov    x2, x9
    0x198617c2c <+108>: b      0x198601e70               ; objc_msgSend_corrupt_cache_error
    0x198617c30 <+112>: b.eq   0x198617c48               ; <+136>
    0x198617c34 <+116>: adrp   x10, 17024
    0x198617c38 <+120>: add    x10, x10, #1904
    0x198617c3c <+124>: lsr    x11, x0, #60
    0x198617c40 <+128>: ldr    x9, [x10, x11, lsl #3]
    0x198617c44 <+132>: b      0x198617bd0               ; <+16>
    0x198617c48 <+136>: movz   x1, #0
    0x198617c4c <+140>: movi   d0, #0000000000000000
    0x198617c50 <+144>: movi   d1, #0000000000000000
    0x198617c54 <+148>: movi   d2, #0000000000000000
    0x198617c58 <+152>: movi   d3, #0000000000000000
    0x198617c5c <+156>: ret
```

Comment: Did you try clean the code and rebuild? Maybe even close and reopen xCode? This message "objc_msgSend_corrupt_cache_error" makes me think is some thing fish going on in xCode

Comment: @IcaroNZ cleaning and rebuilding didn't work. Closing and reopening Xcode also failed to do anything.

Comment: What if you tried changing `Selector("doTap:")` to simply `"doTap:"`?

Comment: @ScottFitsimones assuming you mean this, UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:"doTap:"), this also fails when numberOfTapsRequired = 2.

Comment: @Mark already tried that but the exception still occurs

Answer (score 1):

From the apple documentation:

> Although taps are discrete gestures, they are discrete for each state
>   of the gesture recognizer; thus the associated action message is sent
>   when the gesture begins and is sent for each intermediate state until
>   (and including) the ending state of the gesture. Code that handles tap
>   gestures should therefore test for the state of the gesture, for
>   example:

```
func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .Ended {
        // handling code
    }
}
```

Probability the doTap is getting called before the action finish and is crashing the app.

I hope that helps you.

Comment: @Crashalot, did this change fixed your problem?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `func doTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)` will only be called in the event of a double-tap because you have set that as a condition with `tapHandler.numberOfTapsRequired = 2`.

You could test this by putting `println(sender.numberOfTapsRequired)` in `func doTap`. I believe that as your code is written it should always =2.

If so then I believe that your `if`s are probably not behaving as expected leading to some other consequence which results in the crash.